# Trying to write a script with user input, environment variables, file system operations, conditions, downloading, unarchiving

Tags: linux, bash, nginx

I am trying to write a script according to the following scenario:

1. Put file `Advanced - Linux Shell Scripting – Env.tgz` to any web resource
2. Write script that does the following:

   1. Download file
   2. Unarchive into temp directory
   3. Ask user to choose an environment name. If user doesn’t choose, select default `FeatureBranch` env.
   4. Find a directory with the name of the chosen environment inside the chosen environment directory in the unarchived directory structure.
   5. Check if such directory exists and finish with error message and status, if it doesn’t exist.
   6. Copy from the corresponding hostname directory files to `/etc/nginx` the following way:

      1. always copy files from `unified` folder if it exists
      2. if there is a folder with a name equal to the current hostname in the environment directory, copy files from it to  `/etc/nginx`. E.g., there is a folder `web3-us-east1.local` in the `Prod` directory. Files from it should be copied only if the current hostname is `web3-us-east1.local`
   7. Restart nginx.
3. If any critical error exists (e.g., there is no environment directory or archive file is broken or so) exit from script with non-zero exit code.

But I am stuck at "Ask user to choose an environment name. If user doesn’t choose, select default “FeatureBranch” env."

Here is my code at this moment:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

curl -O ftp://ftp/AdvancedLinuxShellScriptingEnv.tar.gz --user vsftp:aq12w34e

tar -xzvf AdvancedLinuxShellScriptingEnv.tar.gz -C /tmp/
tar -xvf /tmp/*.tar -C /tmp/
rm -rf /tmp/*.tar | rm -rf ~/*.gz

#Asking user to choose an environment name
echo "Enter Environment Name:"
envname=${FeatureBranch:-DEFAULTVALUE}
read envname
valid='0-9a-zA-Z $%&#'
if [[ ( $envname =~ [^$valid] ) ]];
then
    export $envname=/tmp/AdvancedLinuxShellScriptingEnv/
fi
```

Comment: And your question is...?  You have to decide what your tool will do.  Like ask for an env.  If the user just presses enter with no value that is "doesn't choose"?  There is not default way to do this.  Just make sure you explain how to use your tool in the help or documentation.

Comment: But I am stuck at "Ask user to choose an environment name. If user doesn’t choose, select default “FeatureBranch” env." My question is how to pass this stage? :)

Comment: Your user will have to **1** type in a value when he reaches the `read` line **2** OR just press enter, to indicate he does not want to choose.  **3** `read` expects something from the user, there is not going around that.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem with this code:

```
echo "Enter Environment Name (FeatureBranch is default): "
                read -rp"[FeatureBranch/Other]: " -e -i FeatureBranch USER_INPUT
        if [[ $USER_INPUT == "FeatureBranch" ]]; then
                export FeatureBranch='/tmp/AdvancedLinuxShellScriptingEnv/'
        else
                export $USER_INPUT='/tmp/AdvancedLinuxShellScriptingEnv/'
        fi
```